# Why overriding Doctrine_Record::save() give me a strict standard error in Symfony 1.2?

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine

I have the following model :

```
class Model extends BaseModel
{
   public function save($conn = null)
   {
      if(!$this->getId())
      {

        //do stuff

     }
     return parent::save($conn);

    }
}
```

I feel like I am follwing the API description of [Doctrine_Record::save()](http://www.doctrine-project.org/Doctrine_Record/1_1#method_save) signature (Except the weird parenthesis I would give me a syntax error...).

When I run this code, **it works well**  but I get the following warning :

```
Strict Standards: Declaration of Model::save() should be compatible with that of Doctrine_Record::save() in $ROOT/lib/model/doctrine/Model.class.php on line 6
```

I usually turn error reporting to ERROR_ALL, and try to stick with a warning free code. This bother me. I checkout all the  Doctrine source code and greped "save(", on it, trying one signature after an other. Nothing. First time PHP got me for being too permissive, strange hu :-) ?

Comment: aren't you supposed to use hooks for stuff like this? http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_1/en/event-listeners:record-hooks

Comment: Good point. It's much more cleaner.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The correct signature for the save method should be:

```
public function save(Doctrine_Connection $conn = null)
```

Comment: Thanks ! Of course, I should have got that. Now you can use an object in PHP to enforce a type (but not a basic type like an integer if I remember). Feels like PHP is trying to catch up with Java :-p

Answer (score 0):

On a side note: On other functions you may get this error but you will need to use function($event) in place of the above.